# Parent component property doesn´t change in Input() child component in Angular 10

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, filereader

I want an event that fires in child component when the **documents** are loaded.
When I set **readyToUpload** to TRUE in Parent component (into the fat-arrow function) the child component doesn't detect the change on the Input() property...
Why is happening this? Cause the fat-arrow functions?

child.component.ts

```
@Input() public readytoUpload: boolean;

async save() {

this.getFormValidationErrors();

this.submitted.emit();

if (this.errors.length > 0) return;
if (this.frm){
  var check = async (ready: boolean) => {
    if (ready) {
      return;
    }
    setTimeout(check, 2000);
  }
  await check(this.readytoUpload);
}
```

parent.component.html

```
<app-child (submitted)="onSubmit();" [readyToUpload]="readyToUpload">
```

parent.component.ts

```
inputs_to_docs(input_array: Array<any>) {
this.documents = [];
var document_count = 0;
input_array.forEach(element => {
  let doc = {};
  doc.contentType = element.files[0].type;
  doc.fileName = element.files[0].name;
  doc.fileSize = element.files[0].size;

  let reader = new FileReader();
  
  reader.onload = () => {
    
    doc.fileAsBase64 = reader.result.toString();
    
    let docs_aux: Array<any> = this.documents.slice();
    docs_aux.push(doc);
    this.documents = docs_aux;
    ++document_count;
    if (document_count == input_array.length) {
      this.readyToUpload = true;
    }
  }
  
  reader.readAsDataURL(element.files[0]);
});
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like an anti-pattern. Why don't you just use the lifecycle-hook: `ngOnChanges();` in the child component

```
ngOnChanges(){
    if (this.readyToUpload) { // ...code }
}
```

https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges